# How can i connect to asterisk in Node.js

Tags: node.js, asterisk

I want connect to asterisk via socket programming how can i do this?
I know there are many module that we can use of these but i dont want use theme.
I read this [page](http://www.hacksparrow.com/tcp-socket-programming-in-node-js.html) and want to know How can i connect to asterisk in Node.js via socket programming ?
This code is TCP Sample:

```
var net = require('net');

var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var PORT = 6969;

// Create a server instance, and chain the listen function to it
// The function passed to net.createServer() becomes the event handler for the 'connection' event
// The sock object the callback function receives UNIQUE for each connection
net.createServer(function(sock) {

    // We have a connection - a socket object is assigned to the connection automatically
    console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +':'+ sock.remotePort);

    // Add a 'data' event handler to this instance of socket
    sock.on('data', function(data) {

        console.log('DATA ' + sock.remoteAddress + ': ' + data);
        // Write the data back to the socket, the client will receive it as data from the server
        sock.write('You said "' + data + '"');

    });

    // Add a 'close' event handler to this instance of socket
    sock.on('close', function(data) {
        console.log('CLOSED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +' '+ sock.remotePort);
    });

}).listen(PORT, HOST);

console.log('Server listening on ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this [article](http://ageeknotes.com/1392/06/31/connect-to-asterisk-in-node-js/):
We can use socket programming in node.This sample code is for connect via TCP.

```
var net = require('net');
var port = 5038;
var host = "IP";
var username = "User";
var password = "Pass";
var CRLF = "\r\n";
var END = "\r\n\r\n";
var client = new net.Socket();

client.connect(port, host, function () {

    console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + host + ':' + port);
    var obj = { Action: 'Login', Username: username, Secret: password};
    obj .ActionID =1;
    var socketData = generateSocketData(obj);
    console.log('DATA: ' + socketData);
    client.write(socketData, 'ascii');

});
generateSocketData = function(obj) {
    var str = '';
    for (var i in obj) {
       console.log('obj[i]:'+obj[i]);
        str += (i + ': ' + obj[i] + CRLF);
    }
    return str + CRLF;
};
client.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('New Event Recived');
    console.log('******************************');
    console.log('DATA: ' + data);


});

client.on('close', function () {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

Comment: works for me - thanks! ... even if this Q/A set is pure self promotion ;)

Comment: Works for me, too :)